# Performance issue | MySQL Consumes more than 80%+ memory and 2000%+ CPU

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, mysql-5.6, query-performance

Everyday during the peak time my server getting slow or down. Our hosting provider insisting us to upgrade the server but I think some performance tuning issue is there.

Adding the  process information, server configuration and my.cnf parameters below.

**Process Information**

```
 PID  USER       PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                  
 60848 mysql     20   0 34.8g  23g 6416 S 2196.2 82.1  16027:29 mysqld
```

**Dedicated Server Configuration**

```
Size:   'Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz', 2600MHz, 6 Core, Sockets: 2    
Image:  CentOS 6 64-bit with cPanel Fully-managed   
CPU:    Intel Dual Xeon E5-2620 v3
Speed:  2600MHz 
RAM:    32067MB 
CPUs:   2 Physical CPUs
Cores:  12 
Total Cores RAID:   Level 10
Disks:  4
Size:   917GB   
Type:   SSD
```

**MySQL Configuration**

```
[mysqld]
slow_query_log = 1
#long_query_time = 2
long_query_time = 2
slow_query_log_file = /var/lib/mysql/vps-slow.log
performance-schema=0
max_connections = 250
max_allowed_packet=128M
#skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 256M
open_files_limit = 50000
table_open_cache = 15000
sort_buffer_size = 6M
join_buffer_size = 6M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 15M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=2M
query_cache_size=128M
max_heap_table_size = 96M
tmp_table_size = 96M
#low_priority_updates=1

thread_cache_size = 32
wait_timeout = 300
connect_timeout=15
interactive_timeout = 800

innodb_buffer_pool_size=4096M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4

group_concat_max_len=1000000

default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1

[mysqldump]
quick
```

Please help me if there is anything wrong with the configuration ?

**Or**

Do I really need to upgrade the server ?

PS: Hosted  web application in the same server. Also WHM enabled for easy management.

Comment: You have the slowlog turned on; digest it with `mysqldumpslow -s t` or `pt-query-digest`.  Then show us the worst couple of queries for critique.  [_More_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

Comment: Hi @RickJames,  I performed the command and here is the top [list](http://freetexthost.com/qyfeo3azz2).

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to have `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the first few tables in the slowlog.  It would also be helpful if you always tagged each column with the alias (or table) that it belongs to.  Meanwhile, I will make some guesses.

Indexes (or `PRIMARY KEYs`) needed:

```
user_registration:  (usr_username)
user_type:  (usr_type_id)
company_master:  (comp_id)
company_master:  (status, comp_id)
```

If my suggestions don't help enough, then provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the worst few queries.

Because of the implementation of information_schema (prior to version 8.0), `SELECT  data_free...` cannot be sped up.  But why are you doing the query?  There may be a workaround.

Including a test on `status` or `del_status` (etc) sometimes makes optimization more difficult.  There is not a one-size-fits-all remedy.

A tip about `SELECT  U.*, ...`: If `*` includes some `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns that you don't really need, there *may* be a performance improvement by spelling out only the columns you *do* need.

Those indexes should help the first few queries.  Since they comprise 99.9%+ of the activity, you should see the CPU go down significantly.

If you need another go at this, change to `long_query_time = 1`, clear the slowlog, and run for another day.